# Initrd and btrfs raid at rapsberry pi 2

Tags: boot, boot-issues, bootloader, btrfs

I trying to setup a Raid 1 using btrfs.

Generally ArchLinuxARM supports single device btrfs without tweaking anything.
But adding another device and rebooing results in a boot failure "Device not found".

So I figured out, that using an initrd (or initramfs) solves this, as it can hande btrfs.
At Archlinux there is the mkinitcpio tool, which I used:

```
#/etc/mkinitcpio.conf
MODULES="btrfs"
BINARIES="/usr/bin/btrfsck"
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block btrfs filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

And the command:

```
sudo mkinitcpio -g /boot/initrd
```

Then I added this to /boot/cmdline.txt

```
initrd=0xa00f00000
```

And to /boot/config.txt

```
initramfs initrd 0xa00f00000
```

But it simply ignoring this and not using initramfs at boot.
I checked this adding `break` and `break=premount` in cmdline.txt, which has just an effect, when using initramfs.

So where is my fault?

PS.: ArchLinuxARM linux kernel has initrd support. I checked this.